# RMQ server shut down while the application is running

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq

I have an application that uses RabbitMQ. Now, I have a requirement to close the application in case the RMQ server is shut down while the application is running.
Currently, RabbitMq.Client does not send any message/notification whenever the status of the server changes.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should continuously monitor RabbitMQ server and when ever it finds the RabbitMQ server is down  the monitoring service should shut down your application.

It can't be achieved from RabbitMQ end as if RabbitMQ server is itself down which will happen abruptly then how can it send a notification to application to stop.